# Rails Admin - Perform multi-search on tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, rails-admin

I am using `Rails Admin` and I would like to perform a multi-search on tags.

Here are my models :

```rb
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :category_tags, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :categories, through: :category_tags
end
```

```rb
class CategoryTag < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :article
  belongs_to :category
end
```

```rb
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :category_tags, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :articles, through: :category_tags
end
```

I am working on the `admin/article` and I would like to filter with multi-tags :
For example, if I have some articles with `summer` & `job` tags. I would like to filter all `articles` when I write `summer job` for the filter `categories`

Here is my `rails_admin.rb`

```rb
config.model 'Article' do
  list do
    field :categories do
      searchable ['name']
    end
  end
end
```

Thanks for your help ! :)

Comment: There's no easy way to configure rails admin to search on another table. I had to patch rails admin to allow custom scopes, see https://github.com/gotandem-io/rails_admin/commit/a9be59034736e7c57bc2f5b50a3c7675e979dba6#diff-dc54dd6b59865bf3c06fee459e42db5c and https://github.com/gotandem-io/rails_admin/commit/a9be59034736e7c57bc2f5b50a3c7675e979dba6#diff-a03278886bd22519d14b671f73b06e30

Comment: Not sure to understand what I have to do. 
I need to add a javascript + some config into rails admin to do the job ?
Is it not possible try to pass some query-string parameters and filter with a scope ?

Comment: Never mind i just took a look at the latest version of rails admin and on version 2.0.0 they just added support for custom search https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Custom-Search